# How to get access to navigate/goBack function in the class that rendered AppContainer in ReactNative

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've created an app with several pages to navigate through and it works fine when I send navigation requests from child pages (goBack or navigate('...')). The problem is that I need to switch pages from a class that created the `AppContainer`. It looks more complicated. I tried in several ways with refs, but all the time navigate function is not accessible. I want to push a home page in my callback function of the `BasicFooter`.
I tried to use dispatch as well, but the same problem. I am not sure if it is even possible to make it work by reference to `AppContainer` or do I need to build a structure with

```
 <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>{/* ... */}</Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

That's my code:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.refNavi = React.createRef();
      this.goToMain_audio = this.goToMain_audio.bind(this);
    }


    goToMain_audio()    {
      console.log("Object ", this.refNavi.current.navigation.navigate('Home')); //<==Undefined!
    }


    render() {
      return ( <
        View style = {
          styles.container
        } >
        <AppContainer ref = {
          this.refNavi
        }
        style = {
          styles.container
        } </AppContainer>

        <View style = {
          styles.footer1
        }>
        <BasicFooter style = {
          styles.footer1
        }
        clickedAudio = {
          this.goToMain_audio
        }
        clickedMood = {
          this.refNavi.current.navigate('Home')
        } //<== Undefined!
        >
        <
        /BasicFooter> </View>
      }
    }
    const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({

      Home: {
        screen: MainScreen,
      },
      SettingsPage: {
        screen: Settings,
      },
      SettingsMain: {
        screen: SettingsMain,
      },
      ConnectionPage: {
        screen: Connection,
      }
    }, {
      initialRouteName: "Home",
      transitionConfig,
      header: null,
      headerMode: 'none'
    });

    const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Comment: Are you using `react-navigation` v4 or v5?

Comment: <BasicFooter /> is out of navigation, so you can't use navigate there. Use bottomNavigator instead it